# Two tables or one table to store user message edit history in MongoDb

Tags: database, mongodb, chat, database-schema, messaging

I have a messaging system that uses MongoDb as primary data storage. Right now I have a collection of documents. Every document represents a message sent by a user. So, it has the usual fields:

1. msg_id
2. sender_id
3. receiver_id
4. room_id
5. text

I am about to add edit/delete functionality. So, my idea is to have a IsEdited and IsDeleted fields, plus I am thinking of storing all the edit history.

Now, I am trying to find the pros and cons of storing version history together with the document e.g. as an array (an item would have a version_id, timestamp and content) or moving this info to a separate document e.g. MessageHistory.

Currently, I am more optimistic about storing it together with the document itself.
What do you think?

Comment: MongoDB document have a limited storage capacity of 16 MB. Storing message history with the message is fine as long as you understand the limits of much history your application creates for a message. The advantage of storing the related data together is it can be queried together.

Comment: Thanks, actually the storage capacity is a good point.

Comment: We experimented with both and ended up storing it in the same collection, one document per message version. It works for both sql and nosql DBs.

Comment: @GeneS thanks for your reply. So, e.g. a user-edited a message 10 times, and as a result, you have exactly 10 documents, right? How do you detect what message is the recent one?

Comment: 11 documents after 10 edits: the original one plus 10 edits. In our case the `active` document has a non-zero ID. I.e. only the most recent version of the message has the ID, all other versions don't have it.